# algorithm for matrix matrix multiplication of size o(100)

Tags: matrix-multiplication

While I realize this is a niche question, I am wondering if anyone knows of an algorithm for matrix matrix multiplication, that would be really great(meaning use a lot of flops of the cpu or possibly gpu) at matrices of sizes between 100x100 to 500x500?

While I know xgemm and xgemm3m are nice, unfortunately they get the big flops for matrices bigger than 1000x1000.

thanks for the help :)

Comment: my code has a fixed amount of flops needed to finish it -- i want to minimize the runtime, meaning i want high flops at low matrix sizes; xgemm and xgemm3m get high flops only at large matrix sizes

Comment: first i can offer the evidence for small matrices: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/a-simple-example-to-measure-the-performance-of-an-intel-mkl-function  an furthermore for larger matrices http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl#details -- just click the dgemm bench there ... ok this is not quite apples to apples, but as you can see, for the small matrix gflops stay under 100, while for big the go up to 300 ... regarding the other thing, that would not work as runtime scales at least as o(n^2.7) for xgemm3m - meaning the packaging would increase flops but also runtime, nice idea tho

Comment: 100x100 is not worth sending it to gpu. Even a dll function overhead is too much for that. You may need to compute several matrix mult. at once.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but too long for a comment.

I think you are drawing the wrong conclusion from the Intel data.  You seem to be thinking

*Ah-ha, dgemm can zip along at 300GFLOP/s for large matrices, but only at a miserable 100GFLOP/s for small matrices -- where is the method which will multiply small matrices at 300GFLOP/s ?*

I think along these lines

*Ah-ha dgemm is most efficient on large arrays; hmm I wonder whether there are fixed costs attached to calling it which show up as comparatively poor performance on smaller job sizes.  I expect that if there were faster algorithms for those small matrices the bright folk at Intel would have implemented them and made dgemm smart enough to select the right internal code-paths for any given problem size.  After all, dense matrix multiplication is a key part of LINPACK which, for all its faults, is often used for benchmarking high-performance computers and Intel are highly-motivated to demonstrate the excellence of their machinery by using such benchmarks.*

Now I'm not saying that you aren't as bright as the folk at Intel, and my train of thought may be defective, but I put it to you that you will struggle to write, or acquire, a code which outperforms `dgemm` on your small matrices on Intel hardware.  I look forward to seeing the evidence that I am wrong on this.

Comment: gave a lot of thought to this, and indeed there is some overhead, which so far i am yet to understand how to eliminate. Will let it simmer in my head for a while longer. Thanks still :)

Comment: Mark, you are right -- i checked some literature on small matrix multiplication, and those were mostly 5x5 size, which is unfortunately too small; though i did not compare it as oranges to oranges unfortunately.

I will take dgemm as it is and stop worrying about this. Thanks for the help though :)